# Programming on a normal IIS web host + SQL vs. AZURE + AZURE SQL (just a hobby) . Similiar costs?

Tags: iis, azure

I am using a normal IIS web host to host my website and web services.. It is just a hobby and I get very little traffic. I would let to be using Azure instead since I would like an excuse to learn azure.

Is anyone out there using Azure in this way and can tell me about what is thier monthly cost?  I long ago subscribed to azure and forgot about it and a month later had a $90 bill so that really scares me.

Right now my web host + sql is about $25 a month.

Is there a way to have azure shut the service off if it gets over a certain monthly cost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, even a very small instance costs $0.05/hour, and the SLA is only guaranteed if you run two or more instances. That in itself adds up to approximately **$75/month**.

SQL Azure is at least **$9.99/month**. Add to this charges for traffic, etc.

There are reasons why the SQL Azure pricing model is like this. You do get your very own virtual machine instances with dedicated RAM, which you typically don't get in a web hotel, so taking that into account, the Azure price may be reasonable, but isn't very competitive for very small hobby sites.

The official price list is here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/pricing/

Comment: I see. I am hoping this will change. They should be encouraging hobbyist to use it.. I don't mind sharing a machine or whatever they need todo to make is cost effective on thier end..I just need a server to use for extremely light access.

Comment: Is there something lacking from all the shared hosters out there?  (Why do you want Windows Azure to do this instead of just using one of them?)

Comment: @Smarx, as a general comment, if you could carry the message to the powers that be - a lot of developers don't have the opportunity to work on Azure at work and want to play with it at home to hone their skills. I know there are free resources to Partner members but that doesn't help, the idea of becoming a partner is intimidating. I think, what would be great, is perhaps a "Hobbyist Partner". Minimal resources, No SLA, hard capped (or pay as you go), 3 click signon and no credit card required. Just compare acquiring Azure with acquiring Heroku - that is Azures biggest barrier to adoption.

Comment: It is not because I NEED to use Azure. I am a professional developer who likes to tinker with whatever is new so naturally if I could use Azure I could learn about Tables, Queues etc...

I think the main point MS should understand is people like me who want to tinker with these technologies are sometimes the people in companies who make or influence decisions to use Azure a year or 2 later.. So I would think MS would want to encourage these people to learn it and not say 'Shared Hosting is good for you.. don't worry bout Azure'

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure is not designed to host hobbyist sites. You won't be able to beat $25 a month, but then you don't need things like SLA's and HA databass. But, as I commented earlier, it is nice to be able to work with it to train up on the platform.

There are ways of getting onto Azure cheaply.

Firstly There is the free introductory offer. Very much a "toe in the water" just to play/learn the platform. There aren't enough compute hours to host a site.

Secondly, if you're prepared to put in a little effort you can join either the partner or Bizspark programs which will give you access to enough resources to host a site for free, but there is an expectation that you're trying to build "something".

Oh, and for a hobbyist site you don't need the SLA so a single instance is fine.